# Export all texts for localization

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I have many custom views that contains `Text()` wherer Text's content is passed from super-views. When exporting string for localization (**Product -> Export localization**), xCode only exports texts I have used directly in `Text()` as in **code snippet 1**. xCode does not export those texts that I pass from superviews as in `code snippet 2`.

#### 1.

```
// xcode export this. 
Text("Text for licalization")
```

#### 2.

```
struct ListItemView: View {
    var leadingText: String

    var body: some View {
         Text(trailingText)
    }
}
```

SuperView:

```
struct AddItemView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ListItemView(leadingText: "Add")
    }
}
```

**How can I export all texts that I have used in my app?**

Comment: instead of giving type for leadingText to be String, give it like this `var leadingText:LocalizedStringKey` and then try.

Comment: No, it did not work. @TusharSharma

Comment: May be because childView will set its value when we run the application, and not at compile time. So, Xcode is ignoring that view.